# could not submit contact form after changed language in magento

Tags: magento

I have problem with my contact form
I'm using the contact form default of magento for my website
I have 2 stores view, one is magento default called english, one is vietnamese
at the contact form in the frontend , i switch to "vietnamese" and click on the button "Submit"--> the action could not working, the button is working will if store view is english, how to fix it? people can help me to solve this problem,
many thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your log files for any error?

Comment: Hi Gerard de Visser, i have used firebug(Firefox's adds on) to debug and don't have any bug here, and nothing in the folder "var/report"

Comment: Also check var/log folder. Is there an exception.log or system.log file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your contact form is enabled for Vietnamese store view in backend:

`System -> Configuration -> General -> Contacts -> Contact Us -> Enable`

Comment: thanks Gerard de Visser, the Contact Form have been enabled, but still  the  problem.

Comment: thanks Gerard de Visser, i have tested the contact form, it's working well after i have configed like your guide.
thanks again

Comment: Great that you solved this. Please upvote/mark answer as correct for others with same problem.

Comment: Hi  Gerard de Visser , sometime it work well, sometime it is not working
i don't know what is problem
here is the link: http://www.novaweb.vn/contacts
can you help me to test it, please switch to english and vietnamese